# Giving image as background of a button control

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have an image in my resources and I want to provide it as background of  my button in windows phone.
How to do that?
I tried this , but giving an error

```
<Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="131,681,0,0" Name="button2" Width="81" Grid.Row="1" Click="button2_Click" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Images/pause.png"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,36,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/pause.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```